# Finding a basis for P$_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help getting started on this problem, I don't need it to be answered but I just need help figuring where to start.  What should I do?

Find a basis $p$$_1$,...,$p$$_4$ in $P$$_3$ such that deg($p$$_i$) = $3$ for $i$ = $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$.

Comment: You need to explain what is $P_3$.....

Comment: Robert Z explained what $P_3$ is in the answer section.

Comment: Yes, I infered it from context. It was just to be clear, mostly for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. A base of $P_3$ (vector space of polynomials of degree less or equal to 3?) is given by: $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$.

Is $1+x^3$, $x+x^3$, $x^2+x^3$, $x^3$ still a base?